# Changing the current TimeZone in Django doesn't seem to work

Tags: django

I would like to allow the user to change the timezone. I have read and followed the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone)

I can see the dropdown and I can select a different timezone and click on set. Everything gets set, but it has no effect. It still shows Europe/London as the timezone on the page.
What could I have missed?

**My Middleware:**

```
from django.utils import timezone

class TimezoneMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        tz = request.session.get('django_timezone')
        if tz:
            timezone.activate(tz)
```

**Url:**

```
(r'^timezone/', set_timezone),
(r'^$', main_page_view),
```

**View:**

```
def set_timezone(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        request.session[request.session.session_key] = pytz.timezone(request.POST['timezone'])
        return redirect(request.path)
    else:
        return redirect('/') #Thats quite annoying that I have to redirect it afterwards, how can I stay on the same page?

def main_page_view(request): 
    ...
    variables = {'timezones': pytz.common_timezones}
    return render(request, 'main_page.html', variables)
```

**base.html**

```
{% load tz %}{% load url from future %}
    <form action="/timezone/" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="timezone">Time zone:</label>
        <select name="timezone">
            {% for tz in timezones %}
            <option value="{{ tz }}"{% if tz == TIME_ZONE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ tz }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Set" />
    </form>
```

**Main_page.html**

```
{% load tz %}
{% get_current_timezone as TIME_ZONE %}
{{TIME_ZONE}}
```

**Settings:**

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'
USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: request.session.session_key? Shouldn't that be 'django_timezone'? (As per example in django docs)

Comment: Oh dear...Thanks a lot Alex. Last night I didn't see that. Please put it as an answer and I tick it off. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
request.session.session_key
```

Should be replaced with

```
'django_timezone'
```

Comment: Alex, I know now, why I had that stupid mistake. It is a typo in 1.4 doc, which is fixed in dev version. :)  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone